# Finding coefficients in a cubic polynomial given two divisors

Tags: polynomials

I was given a problem, and I'm not sure how to solve it.

> The Polynomial $ P(x) = x^3+ax^2+bx+2 $ is divisible by $ (x+1) $ and by $ (x-2) $.
>
> Find the value of $ a $ and of $ b $, where $ a, b \in \Bbb R $.

Help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Hint: $P(-1)=0$ and $P(2)=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**: $P(-1) = 0 = P(2)$. Can you continue ? here we use the fact that: $(x-c)\mid P(x) \iff P(c) = 0$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Long division will give you the third factor. Then multiply out.

Answer (score 0):

So, for some $r$,

$x^3 + ax^2 + bx + 2 = (x+1)(x-2)(x-r)$

whose constant term is $2r = 2$. So $r = 1$.

$x^3 + ax^2 + bx + 2 = (x+1)(x-2)(x-1) = \cdots$